# projection with array in php mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, php-7

I have a collection with entries like:

```
"Name":"test",
"Description":"some desc here",
"Teams":[0:"idhash1",1:"idhash2"],
"clientId":"clienthash"
```

from which I return all items like this:

```
$filter = array('clientId' => $clientID);
$options = [];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$cursor = $this->conn->executeQuery('dbname.collectionname', $query);
```

Now I want to add another filter on team value:

```
$filter = array('clientId' => $clientID,'Teams'=>'idhash1');
$options = [];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$cursor = $this->conn->executeQuery('dbname.collectionname', $query);
```

which obviously doesn't work. How would I get this to work? I am on PHP7.0, MongoDB 4.0 and extension version 1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

This would be helpful
$insert in MongoDB with Php
http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.insert.php

Comment: why? inserts are not the issue here, i am querying a collection which needs a filter.

Answer (score 0):

What I decided to do was add the teamid's not only in an array but also as separate keys:

```
"Name":"test",
"Description":"some desc here",
"Teams":[0:"idhash1",1:"idhash2"],
"clientId":"clienthash",
"Team_idhash1":1,
"Team_idhash2":1
```

Making querying them very easy and it performs a lot better this way filtering on a team.